# system suspend mode doesn't work Dell XPS

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dell, power-management, xfce

I'm trying to find a reason why the "suspend" mode doesn't work on my machine (Dell XPS 13, model 9370). More specs [here](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/xps-13/spd/xps-13-9370-laptop).

OS info:

```
aechchik@fixie:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I tried to [google](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/6072410) the issue, looks like it might be an issue with the "nouveau" drivers, thus I updated my GRUB accordingly, now this is how it looks like:

```
aechchik@fixie:~$ cat /etc/default/grub 
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

then run `sudo update-grub` and restart.

The issue is that I get a blank screen after resuming from suspend. For example if I'm closing the laptop lid, when I open it again the system doesn't resume and I have to force shutdown (with the power button).

The expected behaviour (given the power management settings) is that I should be able to be prompted the login screen instead.

However, the system suspends correctly if I "manually" suspend it, executing `systemctl suspend`. I'm using an xfce flavour, thus I assigned this command to a keyboard shortcut. Now I'm able to correctly resume from suspend when I open the lid again if before closing the lid I execute the shortcut (or launch the command from terminal).

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Are you sure you have a problem with the nouveau driver?
To my knowledge, there is the XPS 9370 only with integrated Intel graphics unit which uses the i915 driver.